# What plugins needed to open this video?

Tags: plugins

Iam new to ubuntu and I really like it too much but I have really a problem to open [this video](http://www.ece.gatech.edu/academic/courses/ece4430/Filmed_lectures/ResistiveLoadProblems/main.html#) for lecture I hope you can help me what plugins needed because I tried many times !

Answer (score 2):

This is not a plugin, this is an error in the coding. You can check it yourself by inspect element using Firefox.

This is the code of the control buttons ( start , pause and stop)

```
<map name="map1">

    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,45,26" href="#" onclick="lightStop()">

    <area shape="rect" coords="47,0,90,26" href="#" onclick="lightPause()">

    <area shape="rect" coords="92,0,135,26" href="#" onclick="lightPlay()">

    </map>
```

While if you check the function lightStop() or lightPause() or lightPlay() you'll observe the error.

```
function lightPause() {
  swapImage('document.controls','document.controls','../common/controlspause.gif','swapImage1');
  document.presentation.DoPause();
  document.swapImgData[1]=document.controls.src;
      return false;


}
```

you'll notice an error raised

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So in simple words, you don't need a plugin this is some coding error in the site.